# Save XDocument with UNIX line endings

Tags: c#, xml, line-endings

I have a code section looking like this:

```
XDocument xml = new XDocument(
    new XElement("test1",
        new XElement("test2", "abc")
    )
);
```

I now want to save the xml document using the Save method:

```
xml.Save("test.xml");
```

Then I took a look at the file using a hex editor and noticed that it has windows line endings (/r/n). However, I "only" **need** UNIX line endings (/n).

[image: Hexeditor showing line endings]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _I "only" need UNIX line endings_ - and how much do you think you'll save? This isn't worth the coding or the inconvenience when viewing in a simple editor.

Comment: Don't get me wrong here. I really need the unix line endings, because the xml is getting parsed by another program, which requires unix line endings in the xml.

Comment: @ltsstar: The other program has a broken XML parser; XML must be whitespace insensitive.

Comment: @SLaks: thats true, but I am not able to fix it right now.

Comment: @HenkHolterman in my case it saves up to 50kb. Yes don't ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create an `XmlWriter`:

```
using (var w = XmlWriter.Create(path, new XmlWriterSettings { 
        NewLineChars = "\n", 
    }))
{
    xml.Save(w);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = "<?xml version= ...";  //your xml string
using (var w = XmlWriter.Create(path,
                    new XmlWriterSettings
                    {
                        NewLineChars = "\n",
                    })
)
{
    w.WriteRaw(xml);
}
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.